# using HttpPost annotation? Fix so it does not break page

Tags: c#, http

I am building an MVC email form and everything on the tutorial page works except if I keep [HttpPost] the page breaks.

I dont think I am forgeting an Import.

What will fix this so the Email Form will post or rather `[HttpPost]` will not cause the error?
I also tried `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using SW.Models;

namespace SW.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            //ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        //[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(ContactModels c)
        {
            //ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(c.Email.ToString());
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    msg.To.Add("mail@hotmail.com");
                    msg.Subject = "Contact Us";
                    msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
                    smtp.Host = "mail.mail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 25;
                    sb.Append("First name: " + c.FirstName);
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("Last name: " + c.LastName);
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("Email: " + c.Email);
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("Comments: " + c.Comment);
                    smtp.Send(msg);
                    msg.Dispose();
                    return View("Success");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

As Soon as I goto Contact I get the error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Home/Contact

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Is the problem that Contact needs to work with both `POST` and `GET`? I.e. if you add the post annotation, getting the contact page no longer works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without knowing what error message you are getting, but I think this is the problem: You'll want to have separate GET and POST methods for the Contact() action. The GET handles the case where you are viewing the contact page. The POST handles the case where you are submitting your form.

It might look something like this:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new ContactModels());
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactModels c)
    {
        //ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress(c.Email.ToString());
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                msg.To.Add("mail@hotmail.com");
                msg.Subject = "Contact Us";
                msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
                smtp.Host = "mail.mail.com";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                sb.Append("First name: " + c.FirstName);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append("Last name: " + c.LastName);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append("Email: " + c.Email);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append("Comments: " + c.Comment);
                smtp.Send(msg);
                msg.Dispose();
                return View("Success");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

If you have only a single method with an HttpPost attribute, it's only available for HTTP POST requests, so attempting to HTTP GET the page in your web browser will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Actions without attributes are by default GET methods. If you add the explicit `HttpPost` attribute to your method, it **will no longer work for GET requests**, such as displaying the contacts page in the first place.

You can use the [`[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get|HttpVerbs.Post)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.acceptverbsattribute.aspx) attribute syntax to allow both.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have both Get and Post actions or remove the HttpPost attribute and assign your form method to "GET".